# How to append text to output of Powershell command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append text (or comments) to the value returned by this command.

```
 Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'MyContainer' -Context $context | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*LOG_0206*"} |
    Select-Object -Property Name
```

I can't seem to get it to work. I get this output:

```
Name
----
tlog/MyServer/CW_ata_LOG_02062023_100000.TRN
tlog/MyServer/CW_ata_LOG_02062023_120000.TRN
```

I want this:

```
Name
----
tlog/MyServer/CW_ata_LOG_02062023_100000.TRN -> current log file
tlog/MyServer/CW_ata_LOG_02062023_120000.TRN -> current log file
```

When I tried to use the concat symbol '+', I get this error:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'MyContainer' -Context $context |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*LOG_0206*"} |
    Select-Object -Property Name + '-> current log file'
```

> Select-Object: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add examples of how the current output looks like and what the expected output should look like. It would also be helpful if you add your own coding attempts so we can point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please press the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75374717/edit) link below the question to add any new information to the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Revised per your instructions.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'MyContainer' -Context $context | Where-Object {$*.Name -like "*LOG_0206*"} | Select-Object {$*.Name + ' -> current log file'}